# Валидация кода на C#

Tags: c#

Есть файлы расширения cs, которые генерируются утилитой. Мне необходимо программно
проверять на корректность сгенерируемые файлы программно.Возможно это реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте их скомпилировать или поглядите на возможности roslyn

Comment: Файл designer ещё могу представить как сделать валидацию. Очень много особенностей, что б делать валидацию вручную.

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Из чего генерируются файлы? Какой утилитой? Генерируется законченное приложение или отдельные классы? Есть ли информация, какие сборки должны подключаться? И т. п.

Comment: Что означают метки `sxd`, `cxml`?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону пространства имен System.CodeDom.Compiler, и в частности на объект типа CodeDomProvider.
Вот [информация из документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/generating-and-compiling-source-code-from-a-codedom-graph). Проверка корректности в этом случае - скомпилировался код или нет.